# Need to delete from a CQL map using golang, but want to avoid CQL injection

Tags: go, escaping, cql, code-injection

I have things stored in a map in CQL and I want to allow deletion of specific things within that map using a key. The key is passed in from above via an API, so the client can pass in whatever it wants. Here's a snippet of code that explains my situation...

```
func GenerateTrackingIdForDelete(tracking_id string) string {
    if (tracking_id == "") {
        return ""
    } else {
        return "['" + tracking_id + "']"
    }
}

func DeleteAllTrackingURLs(qstringVars map[UrlKey]interface{},reqVars map[string]string, filter string, tracking_id string) error {
    derr := cpool_new.Query("DELETE tracking_urls" + GenerateTrackingIdForDelete(tracking_id) + ` FROM template WHERE vendor_id = ? and advertiser_id = ? and filter = ? and template_id = ? and inst_id = ?`, qstringVars[VendorKey], qstringVars[AdvertiserKey], filter, reqVars["template_id"], reqVars["inst_id"]).Exec()

    if derr != nil {
        return errors.New("Failed to delete all under inst_id/template_id/filter/advertiser_id/vendor_id " + reqVars["inst_id"] + "/" + reqVars["template_id"] + "/" + filter + "/" +  strconv.Itoa(qstringVars[AdvertiserKey].(int)) + "/" + strconv.Itoa(qstringVars[VendorKey].(int)) + " with error " + derr.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here's some background on deletion from a map in CQL: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_map_t.html

Here are some possible solutions, but is there anything cleaner?

- Someone can just pass in a key with a single quote in it, and it breaks the query. I can escape each single quote with another single quote, but is this enough? Is this approach bad because gocql has to prepare the statement for the query on every delete?
- Actually getting what's there and modifying it in memory and inserting it (thereby updating the record). The downside here is more data is being written.
- Having two separate queries (one for the case where there is a specific key to delete, and another for the case where you want to delete the whole map). The downside here is code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, presently, you will have to build the queries yourself to perform patching operations on Cassandra maps.

For general usage, the safest method is your second suggestion; marshalling the full map value, manipulating it and performing a INSERT/UPDATE.

If your map[x]y is strictly defined; i.e. map[int]int I'd have no issue building my own query - but this has other issues such as not taking advantage of prepared statements.